# What should I expect about the battery for a new macbook pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, battery, google-chrome

I bought a new 2019 MacBook Pro, 2.4 GHz Intel Core i5. I feel like the battery is not as described.

I tried with open only one Youtube video on chrome, set the brightness to 75%，and the battery drained 30% in one hour. Usually, it only lasts for 5 hours if I keep browsing on chrome. I also checked the system report, the Full maximum charging capacity is now only 5020 out of 5088.

I only used this new laptop for 2 weeks.

How can I measure energy use to determine if this is normal for a new MacBook?

Comment: Chrome is a notorious battery drain.  Perhaps consider using Safari and compare?

Comment: I guess use Safari would be better, if so, can I take it as I don't need to worry about the battery?